# Should I add reCaptch to my website? I don't want to discourage users

Tags: web-scraping, recaptcha

I'm wondering if I should add a recaptch to my website which gets 30k hits a day. Simply, it rewrites text with a custom made api I created.

I'm not sure how many robots are hitting my site, inputting text into the text box, and using the api (like a web scraper) and am considering using a recaptcha. But personally, I hate running into recaptchas, so I don't want it pop up if a real person is rewriting quite a few articles for a real reason.

**Are there recaptcha settings that are ideal for this situation? Should I use a recaptcha and show it after 3 consecutive use cases for example?**

**Is the google recaptcha smart enough to know it's not a robot?**

**Are there better alternatives, maybe popular solutions which blocks scrapers?**

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Recaptcha v3 is probably what you want. V2 is the one where you have to click on images of buses which is a pain. v3 is mostly unnoticeable for normal users.

Comment: @pguardiario I didn't know there was a V3 that came out, i'll check into it, thanks!